# Unable to integrate google sign in properly in android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin, kotlin-coroutines

I wanted to add the **sign in with google** feature of firebase I connected my app to firebase then added the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint and wrote the below code.
Once I click on the sign in button the intent opens a chooser to select a google account but after selecting one account nothing happens even there is no exceptions or error in the **logcat**.

Code:

```
class SignInActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var googleSignInClient:GoogleSignInClient
    private lateinit var auth:FirebaseAuth
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in)

        val gso= GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()

        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,gso)
        signInButton.setOnClickListener {
            resultLauncher.launch(googleSignInClient.signInIntent)
        }
    }

    private var resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){
        val intent=it.data
        if(it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(intent)
            handleSignInResult(task)
        }
    }

    private fun handleSignInResult(task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>?) {
        try{
            val account= task?.getResult(ApiException::class.java)!!
            Log.i("account","firebaseAuthWithGoogle:"+account.id)
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.idToken!!)

        }catch (e : ApiException){
            Log.i(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e)
        }
    }


    private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(idToken: String) {
        signInButton.visibility= View.GONE
        progressBar.visibility=View.VISIBLE
        val credential=GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken,null)
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val auth=auth.signInWithCredential(credential).await()
            val firebaseUser=auth.user
            Log.i("user",firebaseUser.toString())
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                updateUI(firebaseUser)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun updateUI(firebaseUser: FirebaseUser?) {
        if(firebaseUser != null)
        {
            val intent=Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            Log.i("intent","Intent Started")
//            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Sign In Successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            finish()
        }
        else{
            signInButton.visibility= View.VISIBLE
            progressBar.visibility=View.GONE
            Toast.makeText(this,"Sign In failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat:

[image]

I am very new to android development and this is my first time with **firebase**.

Comment: Do you have `google-services.json` file?

Comment: I think you might be interested in [this repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FireApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firebase/auth/AuthActivity.kt).

Comment: @Marat yes I have included the google-services.json file.

Comment: @Marat I have figured out that the problem is my result code here 
private var resultLauncher 
is always coming out to be **0**
But I am unable to figure out why

Comment: @AlexMamo I have figured out that the problem is my result code here private var resultLauncher is always coming out to be 0 
But I am unable to figure out why

Comment: Most likely you should ask another question for that.